# How to put characters between every paragraph

Tags: paragraphs, plain-tex

I'd like plain TeX (pdftex) to put a specific sequence of characters between every paragraph of its output.

For example: Original text might be:

```
 This is paragraph 1.

 This is paragraph 2.

 This is paragraph 3.
```

and with the fix I'm seeking it would become:

```
 This is paragraph 1.

 zqx3

 This is paragraph 2.

 zqx3

 This is paragraph 3.
```

This is acceptable as well:

```
 This is paragraph 1. zqx3 This is paragraph 2. zqx3 This is paragraph 3.
```

I'm hoping I can set some `\parxxxxx` parameter to do this, akin to a header line or footerline.  I'm looking for the least intrusive method.  If there is an extra `zqx3` before the first paragraph or after the last one, that is completely fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Plain TeX token list variable `\everypar` will be inserted at the start of every new paragraph.

```
\everypar={zqx3\ }

This is paragraph 1.

This is paragraph 2.

This is paragraph 3.

\bye
```

Which is the same as

```
zqx3 This is paragraph 1.

zqx3 This is paragraph 2.

zqx3 This is paragraph 3.

\bye
```

Although this doesn't put the contents in a new paragraph, it might do what you want.  If you need to include a new paragraph in the output, the obvious thing `\everypar={zqx3\par}` won't work - you'll get an infinite loop.  So you'll need some logic to catch the recursion, or maybe use something other than `\par` that fakes a paragraph break (break the line and add a `\vskip`).

Comment: Maybe "\everypar={\vadjust{\hbox{zqx}}}"

Comment: ^ yes that's another way - a good way IMO.  OP wasn't clear whether these were required to be in a separate paragraph (with `\parskip`, `\parindent`, etc) or whether code was wanted to do something formatty. I am guessing the latter, in which case a paragraph probably isn't required, and \vadjust is a good way of inserting `\skip`s, `\hrule`s etc into the page.

Comment: This answer accomplished exactly what I needed.  Many thanks!